# Smooth Excel-like plot with correct legend in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have some sparse data and want to plot them as markers connected by a smooth, interpolated line - like the default behaviour of Microsoft Excel.

There are solutions to this problem easily found on the internet, but I find them unsatisfactory. What they do is: plot the sparse data as one data set drawing it as markers without lines, interpolate it with a method of choice and plot the interpolation as the second data set, with lines without markers.

The problem with these tricks is that in the legend the two data sets will be listed separately. I would expect a single data set depicted in the legend as a line crossing through a marker.

Is it possible in Matlab?

Comment: Depends on what your question is. If you want to plot n interpolated line there are lots of ways to do that. If you are asking how to add a custom legend, you can plot a dummy data set with a red line passing through a marker using `h[1] = plot(NaN,NaN,'r-+')`, then `legend(h,{"Data"})`.

Comment: ...added as an answer

Comment: Do you mean you want only 1 legend on the interpolated line, and possibly markers added but without legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to plot an interpolated line there are lots of ways to do that. You can try generating an interpolated line using the matlab [`interp1()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

Let's create x and y data with no NaN.

```
x = randn(1,10)
y = randn(1,10)
```

If you want 1000 data points where previously you only had a few, that's pretty easy:

```
x2 = min(x):(max(x)-min(x))/1000:max(x)
y2 = interp1(x,y,x2,'cubic')
```

and you can plot your data and spline using

```
plot(x,y,'r+')
hold on
plot(x2,y2,'r-')
```

A custom legend is straightforward when you use handle graphics. You can plot a dummy data set with a red line passing through a marker using

```
h(1) = plot(NaN,NaN,'r-+')
lstring{1} = 'Data';
```

You can then add a legend that points to this data set using

```
legend(h,lstring)
```

You'll end up with something that looks roughly like this:

[image]

The nice thing about using handle graphics (i.e. the `h`) is you can throw whatever data series you want into the legend as `h(end+1)` and `lstring{end+1}`.

Comment: +1, that's how I do it also, but I haven't thought about using `Nan` for the dummy.

Comment: Thinking about it, the legend text 'Data' is not correct - it should be something like 'Data with cubic spline interpolation'. And, personally, I dislike smoothed lines as they suggest you know much more about the process underlying the data than you actually do...